# New smartphone LINE account recover/restore from PC LINE account

Tags: line

I have the following problems and need help:

1. Before I got a new phone (Galaxy S9+), I synchronized my old smartphone (LG 10) LINE account within my new Dell laptop (Win 10).
2. After I switched all info from old phone (LG) to new phone (Galaxy S9+), I login/open LINE and I did "OK" for "Delete old messages and Logs" which no previous messages and logs were displayed.
3. When I login my laptop Line account, I found all messages and logs are still over there.
4. How can I restore or recovery my LINE account (Same phone number but in different smartphone brand names) ? Or, it's hopeless for my sutation.

Thanks,

Tony

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to import the chat history from the PC version into the Android version. The PC version saves the chat as a .txt file, while the Android version saves the backup as a .zip file with various file formats in it.

You can, however, save the chat log of the PC version in the same way as you would on the Android version.